# Simple maze game with four rooms

Tags: lua, adventure-game

I'm starting to learn Lua and in one part of the book I need to convert a "Maze Game" that uses `goto` to another one that doesn't use `goto`.

The maze is the simplest ever made, starting from room #1:

```
---------
| 1 | 2 |
---------
| 3 | 4 |
---------
```

This is the original version using `goto` from the book:

```
goto room1 -- initial room
::room1:: do
  local move = io.read()
  if move == "south" then goto room3
  elseif move == "east" then goto room2
  else
    print("invalid move")
    goto room1 -- stay in the same room
  end
end

::room2:: do
  local move = io.read()
  if move == "south" then goto room4
  elseif move == "west" then goto room1
  else
    print("invalid move")
    goto room2
  end
end

::room3:: do
  local move = io.read()
  if move == "north" then goto room1
  elseif move == "east" then goto room4
  else
    print("invalid move")
    goto room3
  end
end

::room4:: do
  print("Congratulations, you won!")
end
```

And this is my attempt:

```
local rooms = {}
rooms[1] = {
  south=3,
  east=2
}
rooms[2] = {
  south=4,
  west=1
}
rooms[3] = {
  north=1,
  east=4
}
currentRoom = 1
repeat
  local move = io.read()
  local room = rooms[currentRoom][move]
  if room == nil then
    room = currentRoom
    print("Invalid move")
  elseif room == 4 then
    print("Congratulations, you won!")
  end
  currentRoom = room or currentRoom
until currentRoom == 4
```

The above code is working but I was wondering if there is something I need to change to improve it somehow.

Comment: Have you tested your attempt? Does your attempt work?

Comment: @SimonForsberg hi, yest it does work. I'll update my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think overall is good, some bits can be improved but it depends on taste. Take the following comments as suggestions.

As `rooms` is an array, can be defined in a shorter way as:

```
local rooms = {
   { south=3, east=2 },
   { south=4, west=1 },
   { north=1, east=4 },
}
```

Variable `currentRoom` can be localized:

```
local currentRoom = 1
```

In Lua can compare a var to `nil` or ask `not var`:

```
if not room then
   ...
end
```

Branches are exclusive, use of `elseif` can be skipped:

```
if not room then
   room = currentRoom
   print("Invalid move")
end
if room == 4 then
   print("Congratulations, you won!")
end
```

EDIT:

I would rearrange the code at the bottom as:

```
-- Update room state.
room = rooms[currentRoom][move]
if room then
  currentRoom = room
else
  print("Invalid move")
end

-- Reached final state?
if currentRoom == 4 then
  print("Congratulations, you won!")
end
```

that avoids the `currentRoom = room or currentRoom` statement (`currentRoom` only gets updated is `room` is not nil).

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Good job on your first answer.

Comment: Thanks @SirPython. I hope I can engage more and keep learning and improving my skills while reviewing code.

Comment: @DiegoPino Is there a reason why you prefer omitting `elseif`? IMO `elseif` is shorter and more importantly makes immediately clear to the reader that only one of the branches will be taken. Intuitively I'd also assume `elseif` would be more performant because if `room` is `nil`, the second check can be skipped.  Not that performance would matter in this specific case, but as I see three arguments (brevity, clarity, performance) in favor of `elseif` and no obvious one for two `if`s, I'd argue making `elseif` a habit seems like a good idea.

Comment: @ThomasW. I think those are good points. My rule of thumb is to use `elseif` where a `switch` statement would fit. I think `switch` is mostly helpful when there are several branches, more than two. In this case I wouldn't use it, but that's mostly a personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

I see many small mistakes that can be improved upon, Diego Pino did an excellent job of pointing out a few, I'll include his and explain the ones I add in myself:

```
local rooms = {{south=3,east=2},{south=4,west=1},{north=1,east=4}}
local currentRoom = 1
local room --Room is used every interaction, so I declared it out here
while true do --Changed loop for performance reasons
  room = rooms[currentRoom][io.read()] --Move variable was only used once so I replaced it
  if not room then
    room = currentRoom
    print("Invalid move")
  elseif room == 4 then
    print("Congratulations, you won!")
   break --I break here rather than doing an additional check at the end of our loop iteration
  else
    currentRoom = room --Put this inside and else since it's only necessary if another room is picked
  end
end
```